# Where's ConversationActivity in Android from Applozic?

Tags: android, applozic

I try to get started from official document step by step.

I can register succeed , but it crash when i click the drawer's arrow button on ConversationActivity.

I want to find out what's happening  but i can't find the activity which is the ConversationActivity

If i can't find ConversationActivity , how do i find the error and control the button event like drawer's arrow ?
[image]

Comment: My first thought is: what ? And my second thought: is i dont see any ConversationActivity in your package. Third tought: Why are you posting an image and not the code + crashlogs.

Comment: first u need to create a ConversationActivity in the same package

Comment: I have the same confused too...,i'm really not familiar with using source code . it really take me to the ConversationActivity...

Comment: and i think that it will be more clear to describe my situation by using image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note if this is add

```
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.78'
```

in your app build.gradle then you can't edit the files comment the above compile line of code in your build.gradle dependencies

Then clone or download the sample project from this github link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK after downloaded

import the chat modules by clicking  File option-->New-->Import module then go to downloaded project and select mobicomkitui source folder then click finish and then in your app build.gradle file in dependencies add this

```
compile project(':mobicomkitui')
```

Comment: @Sunil Kumar please can you explain me how to use real time chat and video audio calling with real time chat ui customization ??

Comment: @Sunil Kumar    i already implemented real time chat and audio video calling both but i am unable to update chat Ui because  i added below dependency

compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.78' 

And i am also tried with your sample github project but it is only for realtime chat and not support audio video calling

please share sample if you have?
Because i need to purchase this library

Comment: @Amit Desale we have two different sdk  1)one only for chat messaging without audio video calling github sample app link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK and 2)chat messaging with audio video calling github sample app link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-Chat-Sample/tree/master/Applozic-Android-AV-Sample  for complete doc you can check this link  https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to refresh your project

The source says:

```
import com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity;
```

Therefore I think you should uncomment this in build.gradle:

```
// compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.78'
```

Though I'm not sure why it corrently does not come from

```
compile project(':mobicomkitui')
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but that change will show Error:(38, 0) Project with path ':mobicomkitui' could not be found in project ':app'.
<a href="openFile:D:\Android\AndroidTest\TestForApplozic2\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Well, what you would want to do is to clone their sample and make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

You have added the dependency from Applozic, and Conversation Activity is a class of that particular library.
Just download the SDK from https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK to make changes in the conversation Activity.

Comment: It take a long time , i almost forgot what i ask for .  Thanks for your responding man.